# Drupal 8 - Photo Gallery module with Captions

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, image-gallery

I'm new in Drupal and trying to create a photo gallery like the screenshots. Is there a module in Drupal 8 to do that work?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow), here a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvq0vO0X9KQ).

It's a powerful module to show images slider and you can config even the smallest detail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i think it' not like the photos above... I want something like that https://www.drupal.org/project/juicebox but the captions to have black background and the captions to be at the bottom of image..